# Web content is different using Java than in browser

Tags: java, url, bufferedreader, freebase

I have strange problem with BufferedReader reading from web.

This [URL](https://api.freebase.com/api/service/mqlread?queries=%7B%22q1%22%3a%7B%22query%22%3a%5B%7B%22name%22%3a%22Pulp%20Fiction%22,%22%2a%22%3anull,%22type%22%3a%22/film/film%22%7D%5D%7D,%22q3%22%3a%7B%22query%22%3a%5B%7B%22name%22%3a%22Portal%22,%22%2a%22%3anull,%22type%22%3a%22/cvg/computer_videogame%22%7D%5D%7D%7D) content is different in browsers than in pasted Java code.
In content fetched using Java first elements result is empty in browser it is not.

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        String url = "https://api.freebase.com/api/service/mqlread?queries={\"q1\":{\"query\":[{\"name\":\"Pulp Fiction\",\"*\":null,\"type\":\"/film/film\"}]},\"q3\":{\"query\":[{\"name\":\"Portal\",\"*\":null,\"type\":\"/cvg/computer_videogame\"}]}}";

        URL u = new URL(url);
        System.out.println(u.toString());
        URLConnection urlConn = u.openConnection();
        InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(is);
        String line = null;
        String data = "";

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            data += line + "\n";
        }
        br.close();

        System.out.println(data);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Ahh. Figured it out. No space characters in URLs. Just replace them with %20.

Comment: Maybe the site is handling different user-agents differently?

Comment: Are you sure the URL is exactly the same?

Comment: My bet is that they are doing JavaScript for the video - you won't be able to see any JS-generated content unless you run a JS interpreter (or can emulate the exact same calls that the JS is doing).